# Who was hunting who in the 4th Phase of the 287th Hunter Exam?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

In the 4th phase of hunter exams, applicants have to hunt each other, we know some huntings of the applicants:

> ? -> kurapika (#404) -> Tonpa (#16) -> Leorio (#403) -> Ponzu (#246)
> -> Bourbon (#103) -> ?
>
> Gon (#405) -> Hisoka (#44) -> Geretta (#384) -> Gon (#405)
>
> ? -> Imori (#198) -> Killua (#99) -> Umori (#199) -> ?
>
> ? -> Hanzo (#294) -> Amori (#197) -> ?
>
> ? -> Siper (#80) -> Illumi (#301) -> Goz (#371) -> ?
>
> ? -> Pokkle (#53) -> Kyu (#105) -> ?
>
> ? -> Sommy (#118) -> Bodoro (#191) -> Ryu (#34) -> ?

But there are some others that I couldn't find. Does anyone know who are the missing huntings that are represented with an interrogation mark?

Comment: The info in [Hunterpedia](https://hunterxhunter.fandom.com/wiki/287th_Hunter_Exam#Fourth_Phase) is pretty much the same what you shared, so probably this has never been revealed in the Manga or Anime.